# Error in formula Graphic_Location: '{DataTable1.Photo}' A blob field cannot be used in a formula

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am trying to print out images inside rows dynamically in my crystal report using the path that I am providing inside `item.Photo` that I passing to my .Net Framework Api. Then filling it into a dataset as a `byte[]`.

[image]
[image]

```
              DataSet1 dataSet1 = new DataSet1();
        
            
            var ImagePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"];
            DataRow dr;
            foreach (AdditionalInfoViewModel item in reportViewModel.additionalInfoViewModels)
            {
                dr = dataSet1.Tables["DataTable1"].NewRow();

               FileStream(imagePath + item.Photo, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] Image = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(Image, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                fs.Close();
                dr["Photo"] = Image;

                dataSet1.DataTable1.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
```

After I am done filling my dataset, I fill out the `Formula Workshop` with `{DataTable1.Photo}` but I am getting this error `A blob field cannot be used in a formula.`

I had a previous solution before where I fill the path inside the `Formula Workshop` but this caused the report to have a big size when there is multiple records with images.

Any help/suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, BLOB fields cannot be used in formula fields.

Instead, the BLOB field can be placed directly on the report.

Why do you need to have this in a formula?

If the aim is to hide / show the field under certain conditions, then this can be achieved using the suppression formula on the field.